# Can't import Monogame (xna) libraries into my new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I wanted to start use Monogame for the first time and after following the tutorial on how to install on the website. It seems that I can't reach the library at all, it doesn't find any data at all in the Game base class.

Error Message:

> "Error    CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"  Pong    C:\Users\danie\source\repos\Pong\Pong\Game1.cs  1   Active

Any ideas on why I get this error, I use .NET 6. I'm updated as far as I know.

I also have installed everything in Visual Studio (.NET desktop dev tools and cross platform tools etc), and yet, I still can't get it to find the library.

```
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Pong
{
    public class Game1 : Game
       {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add a package reference to the project. Don't know how it is done in VS but usually you can richt-click one "references" or something, and add them. Or in the command-line add it with e.g. `dotnet add package MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX`

Comment: What version of VS?

Comment: @DavidRaab, The references are required Nuget packages, manually adding them is redundant.  This is a bug in VS 2019, and not in 2022.  This is an Intellisense Issue and not a reference problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run the project one time. I suggest using an empty project for the cache load.
The errors should go away.

This technique also solves MGCB editor not loading on new user profile.

The nuget cache is per-user profile. Project's dependencies are only downloaded and loaded on first run, if not already, by running the project.